# Pip install of shapely giving "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 error

Tags: python, windows-10, shapely

I am trying to install shapely 1.5.6 in Windows 10 (python 3). I am getting this strange error.

```
python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\user1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-g1iztcx1\shapely
```

I have tried updating pip but no luck.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error code 1 means the "Operation is not permitted". Usually when that happens in Linux, you can just use `sudo` to resolve it. But on windows, you probably have to right-click on cmd and run as administrator to resolve it.

If unable to resolve it then try using `easy_install` to install the module. Then if still cannot, try updating the setuptools and pip. `pip install --upgrade setuptools`, `pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: This didn't help me, unfortunately... I'm trying to install shapely and still getting a "error: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found"

Answer (score 4):

You can directly download the Shapely Wheel [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely) and run `pip install Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` (depending on the name of the package you decided to download). 
This worked well for me with Windows 10 and python 3.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are still getting errors with the above solutions just make sure that the shapely wheel you are downloading ([here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely)) is the correct one and matching your system's requirements. Make sure you choose the correct 32 bit or 64 bit that also matches the python version (cp37 is for python 3.7). After downloading the file and moving it to your Python directory, run the administrative cmd on Python directory and run:

```
py -3.7 -m pip install Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

(Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is the name of the wheel you decide to download)